# How can I list CSS selectors in a stylesheet based on properties?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to create a list of selectors from a stylesheet if it has the following properties in its declaration. I am specifically looking for a script to list all selectors in a stylesheet that contain all or some of the following properties in their declaration: float, width, margin, and padding. I would just go through each stylesheet manually but there are about 30 and they are really really long. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

Comment: The selectors that I am targeting are definitely being used. I need to list them so that I can override their properties.

Comment: I'd simply use a `grep` ... Do you want to do any further operations on the found matches?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var targetRules = ['float','width','margin-top','margin-right'/*,...*/];
var selectorList = [];
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
for(var i=0; i<sheets.length; ++i) {
    var rules = sheets[i].cssRules;
    for(var j=0; j<rules.length; ++j) {
        var styles = rules[j].style;
        for(var k=0; k<styles.length; ++k) {
            if(~targetRules.indexOf(styles[k])) {
                selectorList.push(rules[j].selectorText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be thorough, you can [parse the CSS](https://github.com/reworkcss/css) and pick out rules that have the declarations you desire. [The AST](http://iamdustan.com/reworkcss_ast_explorer/) looks like it would be pretty easy to traverse.